# Why doesn't my responsive website look good when the viewport is small?

Tags: css, mobile-safari, responsive-design

I have been working on this site for a few days now and am trying to get it to look great when the window/viewport is ANY size... Currently it looks pretty good on a widescreen or normal 1024 monitor for me... However I am having problems getting it dialed out for iPhone / iPad and smaller sizes...

I would like for everything to be responsive and fluid... Currently when viewed on an iPhone only the 1st block looks good... The other blocks have content that extends past the right side of the window so that the user has to scroll over with his/her finger to view the content.

I've played with the viewport (set min & max) and Iv'e now got a min-width of 980px on each of the blocks to make sure the background covers the screen... Not quite sure where I'm going wrong here...

Would appreciate some pointers or anything to make my site more responsive! Tips... WTFS... Etc ;)

Thanks again

Comment: I'd suggest getting a hold of Zurb Foundation or Twitter Bootstrap (recommend Foundation) and using that as your base layout while you get more familiar with responsive design. Once you see how they're put together you will be able to tackle your layout again.

Comment: That was the solution!.... Zurb is great... Although I do have some questions now about zurb... Like how to do easing with their navigation... I am currently fighting the scrollTo plugin as well... no luck... But over all it's much better... A FRAMEWORK was just what I needed... Thx again

Comment: Post the solution as a answer and accept it later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(post these comments as an answer because it turned out to be the answer)*

I'd suggest getting a hold of [Zurb Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com) or Twitter Bootstrap (recommend Foundation) and using that as your base layout while you get more familiar with responsive design. Once you see how they're put together you will be able to tackle your layout again.

Answer (score 0):

change the layout for mobile version with the help of Media queries i mean desktop kind of design will not look good in mobile version for example the main menu is looking good in desktop and for lower screen sizes you have to change the Menu like dropdown..

Comment: Roger... Yeah... I am using media queries already... you can see where they are all set by the little square that changes color next to the logo as the window size changes... I am particularity looking to make it so the width is always 100% of the device width... Among other things... And yes... I was going to make the menu a dropdown eventually thx